# What's the meaning of "defines cell conectivity to ['Points] Indices"

Tags: python, numpy, vtk

I use VMTK to find the centerline in vessel, which is a tool using vtk data. In the    dictionary structure, there are two kinds of data, points and cells. According to the introduction of the dictionary structure, the points is Nx3 array of N vertexes and x, y, z locations, which I can understand. However, in regard to the cells data, the introduction says cells is Mx3 array defines cell conectivity to ['Points] Indices. I cannot understand this. The figures below are the screenshot of the data structure in python. Thank you!
[image: Points data]
[image: cells data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following figure made up of two triangles.

[image]

Here the Point indices and their coordinates can be written as:

```
Index   Points
0   (3,3,0)
1   (5,2,0)
2   (8,5,0)
3   (4,6,0)
```

So for triangle 0, the edges are obtained by connecting point P0-P1, P1-P3 and P3-P0.
Therefore, the connectivity of triangle 0 is (0,1,3). The two triangles can be written based on indices of the points that make them as follows:

```
Index Connectivity
0    (0, 1, 3)
1    (0, 3, 4)
```